# Android rest client - Hyphen names in JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, spring, rest

I having a problem with the nice spring android rest client module.
I was in the middle of creating response types for the rest client, to be able to unmarshall the response into an object. But then I realized I can't.
The response has hyphens field names which prevent me to create a class with this field name.

Here is the example of the JSON response:

```
{
....
created-by: "Wikipedia",
last-updated-by: "Wikipedia",
create-date: "2010-11-21 13:55:37",
last-update-date: "2010-11-21 13:55:37",
...
}
```

So in this case I cant make a class e.g.:

```
class ResponseType{
    private String created-by; //NOT A VALID VARIABLE NAME
    ...
}
```

I tried to get answer from many forum but I failed to find the solution.
I found a lot of places where the guys was suggesting to put an annotation on the field like:

```
@JsonProperty("created-by")
private String created_by;
```

But it didn't worked, because the spring android rest template does not have this annotation.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
String url = "http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=accidentally&langpair=en|hu";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
ResponseType responseType = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ResponseType.class, "Android");
```

I'm curious what is the solution. Looking forward the answers!

Comment: this is not valid JSON ... not because of hyphens but lack of apostrophes `{
created-by: "Wikipedia",
last-updated-by: "Wikipedia",
create-date: "2010-11-21 13:55:37",
last-update-date: "2010-11-21 13:55:37"
}` is not valid, `{
"created-by": "Wikipedia",
"last-updated-by": "Wikipedia",
"create-date": "2010-11-21 13:55:37",
"last-update-date": "2010-11-21 13:55:37"
}` is valid

Comment: @Selvin: I'm using this service call (check the response): http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=accidentally&langpair=en|hu

Comment: it should work if you use jackson json library and use MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter ... and remeber that "create-by" !=  "created-by"

Comment: So are you saying that I can use the jackson json library with the spring android rest client together?
I don't want to use any other library by the way.
The create-by != created-by was just a typo here.

Comment: @FYI: I have updated my question with "what I want to achieve" section

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue.

The problem was that the spring android rest module has a dependency. Especially a third party library.

Let me paste a part of the documentation:

> 2.2.3 Object to JSON Marshaling Object to JSON marshaling in Spring for Android RestTemplate requires the use of a third     party JSON
>   mapping library. There are three libraries supported in Spring for
>   Android, Jackson     JSON Processor, Jackson 2.x, and Google Gson.
>   While Jackson is a well known JSON parsing     library, the Gson
>   library is smaller, which would result in an smaller Android app when 
>   packaged.

pasted from http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/rest-template.html#rest-template-message-converters